# How to publish alpha npm module without confusing the community?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

**Given an useless pet node module**.

./node_modules/salutations.js :

```
var cl = function (msg) { console.log(msg) }
var hi = function () { cl("Hi !") }
var seeYa = function () { cl("SeeYa !") }
exports.hi = hi;
exports.seeYa = seeYa;
```

./script.js :

```
var salutations = require('salutations')
salutations.hi();     // returns: "Hi !"
salutations.seeYa();  // returns: "SeeYa !"
```

./package.json

```
{ 
  "name": "NodeSalutations", 
  "version": "0.0.1", 
  dependencies: {}
}
```

Given its creation sole purpose was to learn about the creation , then publication on npm.org of a minimalist node module.

Given there is nothing valuable on this module, so I don't want to set up a private account.

**Is there a way to publish, test, then remove discretely the module on npm, without polluting npm.org ?**

Edit : I did read npmjs.com's [publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/publish), [unpublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/unpublish), [registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) and [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

Answer (score 2):

You could just upload it to NPM.org and then deal with clean up later, Considering the scope of the module I'm sure no one would get invested enough to mind a removal/change.

Your other option is to host your own NPM repository for testing (this is what I would do) using [something like sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia)

Comment: I'd update the link to verdaccio. https://verdaccio.org/ current fork instead sinopia